# Is there a way to get access to the master mixer or other devices/channels via the web audio api?

Tags: web-audio-api

Is there a way to record the audio being currently mixed down (possibly from another tab/process) on the hardware? Is there a way to input/connect to the browsers mixer?

Studio hardware usually has several input/output channels, mono and/or stereo; is there a way to get these connected onto the graph? Is there/will there be some device enumeration api?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing That you might be able to do is get data from the microphone, and set the system microphone to your system's output (In windows... Manage Audio Devices > Recording > Stereo Mix). Then just use `getUserMedia` to get the audio.

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream) {
    var microphone = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
});
```